# No files matching pattern "src/**/*.{js, jsx}" were found. Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern. React js problem

Tags: reactjs, json, vite

Solving "No files matching "src/**/*.{js, jsx}" were found please check for typing mistakes". Im trying to set up React js as im trying to learn it however i run into that problem Issue of react js cant find files matching pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFnmS.png). The problem is in the package-json file code [Package-json code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AX37.png) and for some reason when I run npm lint the error is displayed on my terminal. My project structure is [Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78Go0.png). How do I fix it so when I run npm run lint there are no errors? Project structure with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJIxQ.png). Is the vite a part of the problem as well or not?

The package.json code is:

```
{
  "name": "adopt-me",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\"",
    "lint": "eslint  \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\" --quiet",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.24.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "vite": "3.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  }
}
```

And vite is

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite"; 
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    root: "src",
})
```

What I did was npm install to see if any dependencies were still not installed which i thought would solve the issue but didn't. I need answers on how I solve the issue. I want the No files matching the pattern "src/**/*.{js, jsx}" were found.
Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern. to be solved but i need a solution? Does anyone have any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Vite has its own way of handling projects, different from traditional React setups.**

1. **Update ESLint Configuration:**
   In your `package.json`, change the `"lint"` script to target all JavaScript and JSX files:

   ```json
   "lint": "eslint \"**/*.{js,jsx}\" --quiet",
   ```
2. **Check Vite Configuration:**
   Confirm that your Vite configuration in `vite.config.js` has the correct `root` setting:

   ```js
   export default defineConfig({
       plugins: [react()],
       root: "src",
   })
   ```
3. **Run ESLint:**
   Execute `npm run lint` again to lint your files and check for errors.
4. **Check File Extensions:**
   Ensure correct file extensions (".js" or ".jsx") and check for typos in file names.
5. **Review ESLint Configuration:**
   Verify your ESLint configuration (`.eslintrc.js` or `.eslintrc.json) matches your project structure and needs.

These steps should help resolve the "No files matching the pattern" issue in your Vite-based React project.